# Сравнить список с классами по их атрибутам python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список `hand = [card1,card2,card3...card5]`, где card - это объект класса `Card`, у которого есть `rank = int( от 1 до 13-ти)` и `suit = int ( от 0 до 3)`.

Задача: отсортировать карты в руке по возрастанию значения rank и по suit (масти).

Пример:

```
<__main__.Hand object at 0x7f7ec7f0a908> with card contents:

    3 of Diamonds
    10 of Diamonds
    Queen of Diamonds
    4 of Hearts
    6 of Spades
    10 of Spades
```

, т.е. расположить в руке карты отсортированные по рубашке и по возрастанию ранга карты.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли это сделать без цикла и "ручного" перебора ?

*Python 3.5*

Что делаю:

1. Создаю 2-их игроков (hands) c 6-ю картами в руке: hands_lst = deck1.deal_hands(2, 6)
2. В цикле прохожусь по списку этих игроков и вызываю метод для сортировки карт ( по рубашке или по возрастанию карт):

   ```
   for i in hands_lst:
       i.sort_card('suit')
       print(i)
   ```
3. Метод sort_card:

   ```
   def sort_card(self, sortby):
           if sortby == 'suit':
    # вот здесь хочу отсортировать список объектов класса Сard 
    # по 2-м признакам: rank и suit
               self.cards.sort(key=lambda x: x.suit)
           if sortby == 'rank':
               self.cards.sort(key=lambda x: x.rank)
           else:
               return 'Error, only \'suit\' or \'rank\' is allowed'
   ```

Вот код:

```
class Card(object):
    """представляет стандартную игральную карту.
        ---Suits:
        Spades   -> 3
        Hearts   -> 2
        Diamonds -> 1
        Clubs    -> 0
        ---Ranks:
        2-10  -> 2-10
        Jack  -> 11
        Queen -> 12
        King  -> 13
        Ace   -> 1
    """

    # use tuple to avoid changes
    suit_names = ('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades')
    rank_names = (None, 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                  '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King')

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=2):
        """Default: 2 of Clubs"""
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank],
                             Card.suit_names[self.suit])

class Deck(object):
    """Generates 1 deck with 52 cards
        Variables:
        self.cards - list of cards, where card is Card object
        Methods:
        shuffle(self) - Shuffle deck of cards
        pop_card(self) - delete last card from the deck and return it
        add_card(self, card) - add Card (obj) to deck
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(0, 4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        """return a string representaion of deck cards
            with one item per line"""
        t = [object.__str__(self) + ' with card contents:']
        for obj in self.cards:
            #s = '    ' + object.__str__(obj)
            s = '    ' + Card.__str__(obj)
            t.append(s)
        return '\n'.join(t)

    def pop_card(self):
        """ delete last card from the deck and return it """
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add_card(self, card):
        """  add Card (obj) to deck """
        self.cards.append(card)

    def move_cards(self, hand, num):
        """ move cards from deck to hand
            hand (obj) - where to move card(obj)
            num - number of cards"""
        for i in range(num):
            hand.add_card(self.pop_card())

    def deal_hands(self, num_hands, num_cards):
        """ creates hands(obj) and give them cards(obj) due to card_num
            hands - number of players
            card_num - number of cards per 1 player"""
        if num_hands * num_cards > 52:
            return 'Not enough cards.'
        l = []
        for i in range(1, num_hands + 1):
            hand_i = Hand('Hand %d' % i)
            self.move_cards(hand_i, num_cards)
            l.append(hand_i)
        return l

       
class Hand(Deck):
    """ represents hand of playing cards """

    def __init__(self, label=None):
        self.cards = []
        self.label = label

    def sort_card(self, sortby):
        if sortby == 'suit':
            self.cards.sort(key=lambda x: x.suit)
        if sortby == 'rank':
            self.cards.sort(key=lambda x: x.rank)
        else:
            return 'Error, only \'suit\' or \'rank\' is allowed'
            
hands_lst = deck1.deal_hands(2, 6)
for i in hands_lst:
    i.sort_card('suit')
    print(i)
```

--------- Сам даю ответ:

Сделал двумя методами:

1. Сортирую список с классами по масти (создаю список со списками карт одной масти), потом сортирую эти списки и заменяю отсортированными списками исходный список:

   ```
   def sort_suit(self):
      lst = []
      for j in range(0, 4):
          lst_1 = [i for i in self.cards if i.suit == j]
          lst.append(lst_1)
      self.cards = []
      for i in lst:
          i.sort(key=lambda x: x.rank)
          for j in i:
              self.cards.append(j)
   ```
2. Сортирую список с классами по масти, потом отсортированный список сортирую методом Шелла по возрастанию с учетом масти карты:

   ```
   def sort_card(self, sortby):
      if sortby == 'suit':
          self.cards.sort(key=lambda x: x.suit)
          t = int(len(self.cards)/2)
          while t > 0:
              for i in range(len(self.cards)-t):
                  j = i
                  while j >= 0 and self.cards[j].suit == self.cards[j+t].suit \
                          and self.cards[j].rank > self.cards[j+t].rank:
                      self.cards[j], self.cards[j+t] = self.cards[j+t], self.cards[j]
                      j -= 1
              t = int(t/2)
      if sortby == 'rank':
          self.cards.sort(key=lambda x: x.rank)
      else:
          return 'Error, only \'suit\' or \'rank\' is allowed'
   ```

По времени работы - второй метод быстрее, для 2-х игроков с шестью картами время выполнения первого метода - 3.886222839355469e-05, второго - 3.314018249511719e-05

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, задача решается несколько проще. Например, если использовать [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Стандартная функция сортировки будет сортировать по очередности полей.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import choice

# первое поле - масть, сортировка в первую очередь по нему
card = namedtuple("Card", ("suit", "rank"))
suits = range(4)
ranks = range(13)

# играем случайные 10 карт 
hand = [card(choice(suits), choice(ranks)) for _ in range(10)]

print(hand)
'''
[Card(suit=0, rank=4),
 Card(suit=3, rank=7),
 Card(suit=2, rank=5),
 Card(suit=1, rank=5),
 Card(suit=2, rank=11),
 Card(suit=3, rank=9),
 Card(suit=2, rank=3),
 Card(suit=1, rank=12),
 Card(suit=3, rank=3),
 Card(suit=2, rank=6)]
'''
print(sorted(hand))
'''
[Card(suit=0, rank=4),
 Card(suit=1, rank=5),
 Card(suit=1, rank=12),
 Card(suit=2, rank=3),
 Card(suit=2, rank=5),
 Card(suit=2, rank=6),
 Card(suit=2, rank=11),
 Card(suit=3, rank=3),
 Card(suit=3, rank=7),
 Card(suit=3, rank=9)]
'''
```

Comment: Кст, есть более привычный аналог `namedtuple` -- `from typing NamedTuple`. Тоже самое, но позволяет в виде класса создавать, пример: [1](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/98213b251308cd641811fb530a90064749875728/Dark%20Souls/ru.darksouls.wikia.com__fandom__bosses/main.py#L11), [2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/https_%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B4_%D1%80%D1%84__crash_statistics/common.py#L13)

Comment: Офф документация: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: @gil9red, да но в виде класса можно создавать только начиная с 3.6. Для 3.5, которую указал ТС, `NamedTuple` конструируется также как и `namedtuple`.

Comment: точно... не заметил что версия питона в вопросе уточнена :)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку на namedtuple. Версия Питона не критична, попробую на 3.6 с namedtuple в виде класса.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Card(object):
    suit_names = ('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades')
    rank_names = (None, 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King')

    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank], Card.suit_names[self.suit])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.suit, self.rank) == (other.suit, other.rank)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.suit, self.rank) < (other.suit, other.rank)


crds = [Card(1, 4), Card(3, 2), Card(1, 2), Card(3, 3), ]  # [4 of Diamonds, 2 of Spades, 2 of Diamonds, 3 of Spades]
crds.sort()  # [2 of Diamonds, 4 of Diamonds, 2 of Spades, 3 of Spades]
```